# Extract a link from a div-container

Tags: html, r, xpath, rvest

As a small side-project I am trying to use R to extract my training data from Polar's website. I am now currently trying to find the links that navigates to individual training sessions from a calendar-overview page.

```
library(rvest)
url       <-"https://flow.polar.com/login/"  
pgsession <-html_session(url)               
pgform    <-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]       ## pull form from session

#log in
filled_form <- set_values(pgform,
                          `email` = "my username", 
                          `password` = "my password")

session = submit_form(pgsession,filled_form)
# Xpath found by using chrome
nodes <- html_nodes(session,xpath='//*[@id="calendarTab"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div/div[1]')
html_structure(nodes) # we're now at the day level where there should be links
[[1]]
<div.training.clean>
```

Where I should find links...

Using chrome, the direct xpath to the link should be:

```
html_nodes(session,xpath='//*[@id="calendarTab"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a')
```

Which results in

```
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

EDIT:
In case it helps, here's what happens when trying to extract nodes when using the selector(?)-path:

```
html_node(session, xpath='#calendarTab > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.training.clean > div:nth-child(2) > a')
{xml_missing}
<NA>
Warning message:
In xpath_search(x$node, x$doc, xpath = xpath, nsMap = ns, num_results = 1) :
  Invalid expression [1207]
```

Ideas to actually find the links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a Polar user so I can't help with an actual example, but open up a Developer Tools window before going to the site. Then go to the site and examine the XHR Network requests as you move around. I suspect the data is either being loaded dynamically that way or via extra or embedded javascript .

Comment: Note that what appears in the browser can be different from what you get in rvest because the browser can run javascript which can alter the document after its been downloaded. Try looking at the HTML that rvest is getting to see if its different that what you see in chrome. If it is, you may need to use rselenium to allow your R code to run javascript.

Comment: Thanks to the both, I suspected that it might be something like that going on, but I did not know how to diagnose or move forward. I will give it shot today.